# R lsmeans adjust multinomial regression model with interaction term

Tags: r, interaction, multinomial, tukey, lsmeans

I want to run a multinomial model with `mblogit()`, which the dependent variable (Treatment) is a three level categorical variable ("treatment1"(reference), "treatment2" and "treatment3"), and the predictors (Exposure) include a 4 level categorical variable("low"(reference), "medium", "high", "very high") and Year information (2016(reference), 2017, 2018, 2019,2020). The model also includes a random effect (Hospital), see below:

```
model <- mblogit(Treatment ~ Exposure + Year + Exposure*Year, 
                 data = my_df, catCov ="free", random =  ~1|Hospital)
```

Now I want to get the lsmeans for each Exposure level by Years like below:

Year = 2016:
Exposure  Estimate    SE      P-value
low         --        --      ---
medium      --        ---      ---
high        --        ---      ---
very high   --        ----     ----

Year = 2017:
Exposure  Estimate    SE      P-value
low         --        --      ---
medium      --        ---      ---
high        --        ---      ---
very high   --        ----     ----

I tried this code to get `lsmeans()`:

```
lsmeans(model, "Exposure", by = "Year", adjust = "tukey")
```

and I got these results which is not what I expect:

```
Year = 2016:
 Exposure    prob       SE      df    asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL
 low         0.333      NaN     Inf       NaN       NaN
 medium      0.333   0.00e+00   Inf     0.333     0.333
 high        0.333      NaN     Inf       NaN       NaN
 very high   0.333   3.91e-10   Inf     0.333     0.333

Year = 2017:
 Exposure    prob       SE      df    asymp.LCL  asymp.UCL
 low         0.333      NaN     Inf       NaN       NaN
 medium      0.333   0.00e+00   Inf     0.333     0.333
 high        0.333      NaN     Inf       NaN       NaN
 very high   0.333   3.91e-10   Inf     0.333     0.333

Year = 2018
```